# Round button with border and shadow

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, shadow

[image]

What would be the best way to create a button such as the one in the image?
I tried:

```
            self.button.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.redColor.CGColor;
            self.button.layer.shadowRadius = 30.0f;
            self.button.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;
            self.button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 30.0f);
            self.button.clipsToBounds = NO;

            [self.button setNeedsDisplay];
```

But this just add a minor very blury shadow not at all like in the image.

Answer (score 0):

Hey @user426132 set UIbutton background image and Try this code

For **Objective-c**

```
self.button.layer.cornerRadius = self.button.frame.size.width / 2;
self.button.layer.masksToBounds = false;
self.button.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.grayColor.CGColor;
self.button.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
self.button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
self.button.layer.shadowRadius = 10;
self.button.layer.shouldRasterize = true;
self.button.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.mainScreen.scale;
```

For **Swift 4.2**

```
    self.btnShadow.layer.cornerRadius =  self.btnShadow.frame.size.width / 2
    self.btnShadow.layer.masksToBounds = false
    self.btnShadow.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    self.btnShadow.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    self.btnShadow.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
    self.btnShadow.layer.shadowRadius = 10
    self.btnShadow.layer.shouldRasterize = true
    self.btnShadow.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
```

Output is here [image] in black cross is image

Comment: What do you mean set Background image?

Comment: If you want to get same to same [https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1tVW.png]  Button looks so set your image to Button image.